# Limit characters in Inputfield

Tags: xcode, swift

How can I limit the amount of characters that a user can put into a text field?
My code until now looks like this:

```
@IBAction func findBudget(sender: AnyObject) {

    var enteredBudget = enterBudget.text.toInt()

    if enteredBudget != nil {
```

I am a swift beginner, which means I would be happy if you could write me an very precise answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for you:

**If you want to use TextField**

```
import UIKit
// Add your UITextFieldDelegate Here
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var userText: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Here assign delegate to self
    self.userText.delegate = self
}

//Use this delegate function
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{

    var newLength:Int = (userText.text as NSString).length + (string as NSString).length - range.length
    var remainingChar1:Int = 5 - newLength

    return (newLength > 5) ? false : true
    }
}
```

In this `delegate` function I set limit to 5 so user can enter only 5 characters into `textFied`. You can set as per your need.

**If you want to use textView:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.textView.delegate = self
}
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool{

    var newLength:Int = (textView.text as NSString).length + (text as NSString).length - range.length
    var remainingChar:Int = 5 - newLength
    return (newLength > 5) ? false : true
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your `textField`'s delegate to view controller and add this:

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate{
   func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{
      let charsLimit = 5
      return (countElements(textField.text) - range.length + countElements(string) < charsLimit)
}
```

Also you could set `Keyboard type` to "Number Pad" in the Interface Builder in case you want just numbers:
[image]